# Is there an algorithm to detect the intersection between a line and a Catmull-Clark subdivision surface?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, vulkan, raytracing, bspline

Is there a known way to find all intersection points between a line and Catmull-Clark subdivision surface? I am trying to learn more about this topic to write a Vulkan raytracing intersection shader to directly detect an intersection without first converting it to a triangular mesh.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "Catmull-Clark subdivision surface"? Is it CC subdivision, a technique to subdivide a mesh?

Comment: @codetiger If you have ever used any mainstream 3D software, it's exactly what you're thinking of. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface

Comment: If that is the case, CC subdivision surface can be of any geometric shape and other than finding all possible intersections between line and the shape, I don't see any short cuts. For better performance, you can possibly use a less subdivided shape.

Comment: The quickest way is using bounding box intersection, which might not be perfect in all shapes. Next quick option is by iterating through triangles and finding the intersections between line and each triangle.

Comment: @codetiger That's the problem. I was looking for a purely mathematical solution to intersect with the limit surface (i.e. the perfectly-smooth infinitely subdivided shape that isn't made of triangles). I have read some papers about evaluating matrices and such, but it's been a while since my last algebra class, and I don't understand very much about it. This might seem like a waste of time, but I would think that having a few very expensive intersection detections in this case would be faster than having a mesh of triangles that has been subdivided many times.

Comment: Purely mathematical solution will work if you can define the geometry in a equation. Usually ray tracing engines, allow defining the object in different mathematical expressions and also allow custom triangle based mesh. As you mentioned Catmull-Clark subdivision surface, am not sure if it makes sense in mathematically defined shapes. As subdivision is much easier to generate using the equation than using CC subdivision.